# Optimistic Locking with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, locking

We are kicking a new project and starting to use Laravel 4.
Do you know if it has support for optimistic locking out of the box?
It seems that it does not as I found almost no reffrences and some talkback about that on http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-in-laravel-4/

If anyone has added it and can share some guidelines for the implementation it would be great.

Thanks, Avi

Comment: i am using something similar to this http://fideloper.com/laravel4-etag-concurrency-control since my project is APi based... and also there are model events and timestamps which could be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still doesn't support. I had an issue about this on Github, but issues are down for Laravel: https://www.google.com.br/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=&ie=UTF-8&q=laravel%20optimistic%20locking%20github